# how to setup environment variable CA_DATA in tomcat config

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, environment-variables, production-environment

I am trying to implement & access a native API(.so) in my java web project which look for CA_DATA variable.

```
 set it in .bashrc as -
export CA_DATA=/app/IstCorrectAddress/Data;
```

i can see this in path when echo but problem is when .war deployed on tomcat server cant see the variable.

I want to set this environment variable somewhere in tomcat config which can be seen by war on startup. please suggest where and how to set it so that it can access.

Please suggest.

Comment: Hard to say. How are you running Tomcat? Using the default Unix startup script? Who does tomcat run as? Which OS exactly are you using?

Comment: running tomcat from directly bin/startup.sh .tomcat run under root user .Os is linux(64 bit). setting up Environment variable should be same (if not running as service etc/init.d ),right? I am not sure so posted this question but we have a way to set it up on /app/apache-tomcat-7.0.41/conf/Catalina/localhost  location.

Comment: In that case you probably need to look through `startup.sh` and see if it reads variables from somewhere. Often there is a file like `/etc/default/tomcat` which the script imports. Setting your environment if tomcat isn't running as you ain't going to do much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your using JNI(java native Interface here). If you want to add libraries to tomcat, the way I do is to set it up in setevn.sh or setenv.sh, depends on which environment you are in

In this file, you will have this

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% /<path to proerties>/xyz.so
```

In catalina.bat, I would have these lines

```
rem Get standard environment variables
if "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotSetenvHome
if exist "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\setenv.bat"
goto gotSetenvBase
:gotSetenvHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat" call "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat"
:gotSetenvBase
```

You can set the path in  profile.bash. Hope this helps.